# Script to distribute a large number of files in to smaller groups

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, applescript

I have folders containing large numbers of files (e.g. 1000+) of various sizes which I want to move in to smaller groups of, say, 100 files per folder.

I wrote an Apple Script which counted the files, created a numbered subfolder, and then moved 100 files in to the new folder (the number of files could be specified) which looped until there were less than specified number of files which it moved in to the last folder it created.

The problem was that it ran horrendously slowly. I'm looking for either an Apple Script or shell script I can run on my MacBook and/or Linux box which will efficiently move the files in to smaller groups.

How the files are grouped is not particularly significant, I just want fewer files in each folder.

Comment: If you show your code we can improve it.

Comment: @Dennis: That's the slightly embarrassing part. I lost the script when my laptop drive died and now, while considering rewriting the script, I thought I would seek some help from the SO community first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
DIR=$1
BATCH_SIZE=$2
SUBFOLDER_NAME=$3
COUNTER=1

while [ `find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f| wc -l` -gt $BATCH_SIZE ] ; do
  NEW_DIR=$DIR/${SUBFOLDER_NAME}${COUNTER}
  mkdir $NEW_DIR
  find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -n $BATCH_SIZE | xargs -I {} mv {} $NEW_DIR
  let COUNTER++
if [ `find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f| wc -l` -le $BATCH_SIZE ] ; then
  mkdir $NEW_DIR
  find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -n $BATCH_SIZE | xargs -I {} mv {} $NEW_DIR
fi
done
```

The nested if statement gets the last remaining files. You can add some additional checks as you see needed after you modify for your use.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. I copied the first three lines of the loop to after the "done" and that moved the remaining files in to the last folder. It processed about 1100 files in 6 seconds :)

Comment: Although I noticed one (minor) problem. The first folder only has `BATCH_SIZE - 1` files in it, the other folders have the correct number. It's not problem though I don't need the number of files to be exactly the same, I just need a more manageable number in each folder.

Answer (score 3):

This is a tremendous kludge, but it shouldn't be too terribly slow:

```
rm /tmp/counter*
touch /tmp/counter1
find /source/dir -type f -print0 | 
    xargs -0 -n 100 \
        sh -c 'n=$(echo /tmp/counter*); \
               n=${n#/tmp/counter}; \
               counter="/tmp/counter$n"; \
               mv "$counter" "/tmp/counter$((n+1))"; \
               mkdir "/dest/dir/$n"; \
               mv "$@" "/dest/dir/$n"' _
```

It's completely indiscriminate as to which files go where.

Comment: I've not had a chance to try this on my Linux box but when I ran it on my MacBook I get the error:   _: line 3: /tmp/counter1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/tmp/counter1")   I'll have a go at working it out but do you have any idea as to what might be wrong?

Comment: @Tony: Sorry, I forgot to put the directory in one line. It should be `n=${n#/tmp/counter}; \\`. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to solve the problem of directories with too many files in them is to subdivide by the the first couple characters of the name. For example:

Before:

```
aardvark
apple
architect
...
zebra
zork
```

After:

```
a/aardvark
a/apple
a/architect
b/...
...
z/zebra
z/zork
```

If that isn't subdividing well enough, then go one step further:

```
a/aa/aardvark
a/ap/apple
a/ar/architect
...
z/ze/zebra
z/zo/zork
```

This should work quite quickly, because the move command that your script executes can use simple glob expansion to select all the files to move, ala `mv aa* a/aa`, as opposed to having to individually run a move command on each file (which would be my first guess as to why the original script was slow)

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful tip. I'll have to have a go at scripting a solution and see how it performs.